# hibernate exception on saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, exception

I'm having an strange problem when I try to save or update a simple entity:

```
   @Entity
public class TimeTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = false, targetEntity = Subject.class)
    private Set<Subject> courses = new HashSet<Subject>();


@Entity
public class Subject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean mandatory = false;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer credits;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Period.class)
    private Set<Period> periods = new HashSet<Period>();
```

`the DAO class

```
public synchronized void saveOrUpdate(E obj) {

    log.log(Level.DEBUG, "iniciando save de " + obj.toString());
    Session s = this.getSession();
    s.beginTransaction();
    s.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    try {
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        s.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    s.close();

    log.log(Level.DEBUG, "save concluido com sucesso");

}
```

and my test code:

```
GenericDAO<TimeTable> asd = new GenericDAO<TimeTable>(TimeTable.class);
GenericDAO<Subject> qwe = new GenericDAO<Subject>(Subject.class);
Set<Subject> aasdasd = new HashSet<Subject>();
aasdasd.addAll(qwe.findAll());
TimeTable zxc = new TimeTable(aasdasd);
asd.saveOrUpdate(zxc);
```

but i'm getting exception on saveOrUpdate line:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:52)
```

the exception point to the line s.saveOrUpdate(obj); in my dao class, but it doens't happen when i try to do exactly the same thing with other entities [even more complex].

Does anybody has any tip about it?

Comment: do you have any value in your input data that might be breaking SQL created by hibernet? You can verify that first.

Comment: I just have integers and booleans I can't realize how it could possible break the statement. I thought it was a variable name, but checked all and changed some but still happening

Comment: @RafaelLima can you print the sql that is being executed. As per the exception the statement is not being generated properly. Can you debug and get the sql statement

Comment: the exception happens before the show_sql print something, but deep debugginh hibernate code I saw that the generated statement was like
insert into TimeTable () 1

where 1 is supposed to be the identifier, it really seams to be a bug in hibernate

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

1) I *always* specify @Table in my entities, just to make sure the name/casing is correct.

2) I believe SQLITE is case sensitive by default, if you don't have @Table I'm assuming (because I've never done it this way) that the class name == table name and that the case must match up.  Any chance that you have a lower-case name in your database?

3) Also don't see your JPA properties, is it possible your connection information does/incorrectly specify the database?  [Granted, I've never used SQLITE, but the chances of Hibernate creating an invalidly-formatted SQL statement seems unlikely.]

4) Last statement on #3, you do have the correct dialect selected, right?

Comment: 1) is not related to table/columns names or case sentive, because if was i couldn't select in that entity and i can.
4) i think i've the correct dialect is working for other more complex projects

Answer (score 0):

Well, I apreciated your help but i just get annoyed of this unknown error and switch the database to a derby one. and just switching the jdbc parameters worked smothly